# There is any way to use angular ui-views - highlight module in order to highlight all words from array?

Tags: angularjs

There is any way to use angular ui-views  - highlight module in order to highlight all words from array?

instead of:

```
<p ng-bind-html="'Hello there, how are you today' | highlight:'how':caseSensitive"></p>
```

I have now, i want to replace `highlight:'how'` in list of words I have in order to highlight all those words in the text.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to modify the string to have `span` tags or something similar so that you can highlight specific parts of the text. Then you would need to use `ng-bind-html` in the unsafe way, by using `$sce.trustAsHtml()`. See [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/T8hiqDXEvHG0J5GhhkSH?p=preview).

To insert the `span` tags, you can use regex.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-bind-html="test | highlight : 'you' : false : 'yellow'"></div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']).filter('highlight', function($sce) {
    return function(html, key, sensitive, color) {
        var flags = sensitive ? 'g' : 'gi';
        var new_html = html.replace(new RegExp('(' + key + ')', flags), '<span style="background-color:' + color + ';">$1</span>');
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(new_html);
    };
}).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = 'hello, this is a test. how are you? what is your name?';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a case-sensitive match, you could just do it like this:

```
<p ng-bind-html="'Hello there, how are you today' | highlight:'how|you|ell'"></p>
```

and all the words i.e. "how", "you", and "ell" will be highlighted.

Again, note that this trick doesn't work in the case-sentitive mode.

Comment: great! thanks! but there is a way to use it with scope variable?

Comment: find the way - 

<p ng-bind-html="'Hello there, how are you today' | highlight:var:caseSensitive"></p>